# Don't request data again after using location.back() in Angular 6 - ReplaySubject necessary?

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, angular-ui-router

I am using BehaviourSubject from my service to get all data from BackEnd which I subscribe in my mainComponent using the async pipe.

If I now route to another subComponent and then click for example on a back button (uses Location.back() function) to get back to my mainComponent it always fetchs all data with a new request from BackEnd.

I guess this comes from using async pipe as it unsubscribes the BehaviourSubject when leaving the mainComponent.

Do I need to implement some caching strategy for this or can this be solved using a ReplaySubject with the size of all data i fetch from mainComponent?

Below my Code:

Service:

```
private subject$: BehaviorSubject<Setting[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Setting[]>([]);

fetchData() {
  const fetch$: Observable <Setting[]> = this.getSettings().pipe(share());
  fetch$.pipe(
      map(allSettings => this.subject$.next(allSettings))
    );
  return fetch$;
}
```

MainComponent:

```
data: Observable<Setting[]>;

// Load Setting while starting
ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this.apiService.fetchData();
}
```

MainComponent.html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let s of data | async">
  <!--Do Something...-->
</tr>
```

SubComponent:

```
goBack(): void {
  this.location.back();
}
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have in ngOnInit() will be executed when you "come back" to component. You can put your data in variable in a service and then on ngOnInit() check to see are there any data in service and if there is do not ask for them from a server again.

```
if(myservice.data) {
do nothing}
else {
myservice.data = this.apiService.fetchData();}
```

Comment: is it ok if I add my two services in app.module as provider and then inject my apiService in constructor from dataService?

Comment: @student18 you can have as many services as you need. There is no limit in number of injected services in one component. You simply inject both services in your component and call them when you need them.

Comment: Ok thanks, and with data variable in dataService, I guess you mean an Observable?

Comment: @student18 No observable. It can be anything (number, string, array...). You use observable and subscribe to it to get some data, but you need something to "put" that data in and to keep it. That is some variable you create.